# Scala : Way to use a function directly into the println(...) using string interpolation

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, string-interpolation

With Scala 2.10+ String Interpolation can be made. So I have this question. How can you do this:

```
println(f"$foo(100,51)%1.0f" )
```

considering foo is a function like:

```
def foo(x1:Int , x2:Int) : Double  = { ... }
```

From what I understand the way this is evaluated makes foo considered to have no arguments beacause the message I get is :

```
missing arguments for method foo in object bar;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
```

I tried using parenthesis but errors still occur.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wrap the call to `foo` in curly brackets.

For instance let

```
def foo(x1: Int, x2: Int) : Double  = Math.PI * x1 * x2
```

where for example

```
foo(100,51)
res: Double = 16022.122533307946
```

Then

```
scala> println(f"${foo(100,51)}%1.0f" )
16022
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just did not want to use a val in my program so that it can be fully Functional.

Comment: What about `val` makes it non-functional?

Comment: No use of local variables.

Comment: @DoomProg You're mistaken as to what that means. A `val` is not a variable - it is a value. A variable can change, a value cannot. Functional languages bind local values all the time - look at any ML family program and you're bound to see a lot of `let` clauses to declare immutable local values. You can feel free to use `val` as much as you like in Scala without fear of breaking a functional style.

Comment: I'd also add that I'm often glad I have distinct line numbers when I get a gnarly stack track in my error log.

Comment: @DoomProg To follow on @KChaloux, the big issue is with mutability, especially when it's observable from outside a function/object. Functional programming emphasizes referential transparency, which is the property of always returning the same result given the same parameters. It is possible to use `var` and still preserve R.T., although I can't think of a time when this would be necessary. I typically use lots of `val`s to break up my code into easily understandable steps. There's no award for most operations per line :)

Comment: Thank you all for these clarifications! I fully understand your point.